# Python: loop over a list of string and using split()

Tags: python, string, list, loops, split

I'm trying to split the elements of a list:

```
text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
        'James Gosling\n']

newlist = ['James', 'Fennimore', 'Cooper\n', 'Peter', 'Paul,', 'and', 'Mary\n',
        'James', 'Gosling\n']
```

My code so far is:

```
newlist = []

for item in text:
    newlist.extend(item.split())

return newlist
```

And I get the error:

`builtins.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show that error.

Comment: @mogambo `split` is never called on `text`, but on `item`.

Comment: Oops! You're right... My bad. Deleting comment.

Comment: probably duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/split-elements-of-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `split()` here as it'll also strip the trailing `'\n'`, use `split(' ')`.

```
>>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
...         'James Gosling\n']
>>> [y for x in text for y in x.split(' ')]
['James', 'Fennimore', 'Cooper\n', 'Peter,', 'Paul,', 'and', 'Mary\n', 'James', 'Gosling\n']
```

And in case the number of spaces are not consistent then you may have to use regex:

```
import re
[y for x in text for y in re.split(r' +', x)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Aशwini चhaudhary's response, if you're interested in removing the trailing `,`s and `\n`s from your string fragments, you could do

```
[y.rstrip(',\n') for x in text for y in x.split(' ')]
```