# Python: trying to get three elements of a list with slice over a iterator

Tags: python, list

I'm new to python.

I'm trying to create another list from a big one just with 3 elements of that list at a time.

I'm trying this:

```
my_list = ['test1,test2,test3','test4,test5,test6','test7,test8,test9','test10,test11,test12']
new_three = []
for i in my_list:    
    item = my_list[int(i):3]
    new_three.append(item)

    # here I'll write a file with these 3 elements. Next iteration I will write the next three ones, and so on...
```

I'm getting this error:

```
item = my_list[int(i):3]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'test1,test2,test3'
```

I also tried:

```
from itertools import islice
for i in my_list:
    new_three.append(islice(my_list,int(i),3))
```

Got the same error. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT:

After many tries with help here, I could make it.

```
listrange = []
for i in range(len(li)/3 + 1):
    item = li[i*3:(i*3)+3]
    listrange.append(item)
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Related: [Loop over a list of string using split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307844/python-loop-over-a-list-of-string-and-using-split?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: When using a for loop, python will iterate over list *members*, not indices, as evidenced by your error message. When you say 3 elements of the list at a time, do you mean 3 strings at a time from my_list ?

Comment: What Kevin said. The `my_list` given above only contains 4 elements.

Comment: You may find the answers here helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks Also check the linked pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
my_list = ['test1,test2,test3','test4,test5,test6','test7,test8,test9','test10,test11,test12']
for item in my_list:
    print "this is one item from the list :", item    
    list_of_things = item.split(',')
    print "make a list with split on comma:", list_of_things
    # you can write list_of_things to disk here
    print "--------------------------------"
```

In response to comments, if you want to generate a whole new list with the comma separated strings transformed into sublists, that is a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [item.split(',') for item in my_list]
```

And to split it up into groups of three items from the original list, see the answer linked in comments by PM 2Ring, [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks)

I have adapted that to your specific case here:

```
my_list = ['test1,test2,test3','test4,test5,test6','test7,test8,test9','test10,test11,test12']

for i in xrange(0, len(my_list), 3):
    # get the next three items from my_list
    my_list_segment = my_list[i:i+3]

    # here is an example of making a new list with those three
    new_list = [item.split(',') for item in my_list]
    print "three items from original list, with string split into sublist"
    print my_list_segment
    print "-------------------------------------------------------------"

    # here is a more practical use of the three items, if you are writing separate files for each three
    filename_this_segment = 'temp' # make up a filename, possibly using i/3+1 in the name
    with open(filename_this_segment, 'w') as f:
        for item in my_list_segment:
            list_of_things = item.split(',')
            for thing in list_of_things:
                # obviously you'll want to format the file somehow, but that's beyond the scope of this question
                f.write(thing)
```

Comment: #first iteration
`[['test1', 'test2', 'test3'],['test4', 'test5', 'test6'],['test7', 'test8', 'test9']]`

#second iteration
`[['test10', 'test11', 'test12'],[# nextt group of three],[# next another group of three]]`
        
# third iteraction
`[[# next other group of three],[# next other group of three],[# next other group of three]]`
                
# and son on...

Comment: Hold on, I think you want the question linked in comments by PM 2Ring, in addition to using split(',').  Updating ...