# Python: split elements of a list

Tags: python, list, split, element

As a follow up to this question: [split elements of a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/split-elements-of-a-list-in-python)

Given the list:

```
l = ['element1\t0238.94', 'element2\t2.3904', 'element3\t0139847', '']
```

How do I get everything after the `\t`?

I tried:

```
>>> [i.split('\t', 1)[1] for i in t]                                                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is it because I have `''` at the end? How do I exclude it?

Comment: user1899415, can you accept an answer? You have two answers for nearly a year now.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [175]: l = ['element1\t0238.94', 'element2\t2.3904', 'element3\t0139847', '']

In [176]: [i.partition('\t')[-1] for i in l]
Out[176]: ['0238.94', '2.3904', '0139847', '']
```

Or, if you only want to consider the elements with a `'\t'` in them:

```
In [177]: [i.partition('\t')[-1] for i in l if '\t' in i]
Out[177]: ['0238.94', '2.3904', '0139847']
```

Comment: I beat you to posting the second method (I used `split()`).

Comment: @smci Great job!  Where would you like to pick up your prize?

Answer (score 4):

Your case is easier, because you can exploit that we throw away everything before the tab:

```
l = [x.split('\t')[-1] for x in l]
['0238.94', '2.3904', '0139847', '']
```

Note we used [-1] instead of [1], so we don't blow up with IndexError when we split('', '\t') and only get one group `['']` as a result.
'-1' means 'the last index', so -1 will be equivalent to 1 when there are 2 split-groups, and 0 when there is only 1.