# Pythonic way performing split on all elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

I want to end up with a list that contains the first elements of a split on all items of a list. That is. `input_list = [‘A1 - Some Text’, ‘A2 - Other Text’]` should result as `output_list = [‘A1’, ‘A2’]`. What is the most Pythonic (clever) way of doing this? Extra points for not needing multiple list variables.

**UPDATE:**

Updating with my initial attempt:

```
input_list = [‘A1 - Some Text’, ‘A2 - Other Text’]
output_list = []

for element in input_list:
    output_list.append(element.split(' - ')[0]))
```

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52122876/edit) to include your latest attempt(s)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split elements of a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/split-elements-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: "clever" != "pythonic"

Comment: @jpp I’ve updated my question.

Comment: @jpp You are correct, that post helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `l` contains your list, I think something like: `[i.split('-')[0] for i in l]` should provide a good start.

Comment: Thank you @Hans! This is exactly what I was looking for.