# Splitting a list with regex

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, pycharm

I am having some trouble trying to split each element within a nested list. I used this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/how-to-split-elements-of-a-list) for my first split. I want to do another split to the now nested list. I thought I could simply use the same line of code with a few modifications `goal2 = [[j.split("") for j in goal]]`, but I continue to get a common error: `'list' object has no attribute 'split'`. I know that you cannot split a list, but I do not understand why my modification is any different than the linked method. This is my first project with web scraping and I am looking for just the phone numbers of the website. I'd like some help to fix my issue and not a new code so that I can continue to learn and improve my own methods.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


source = requests.get('https://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/ORxmasnw.php').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

info = soup.findAll(text=re.compile("((?:\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?(?:\s|-|\.)?\d{3}(?:\s|-|\.)\d{4})"))[:1]
goal = [i.split(".") for i in info]
goal2 = [[j.split("") for j in goal]]

for x in goal:
    del x[2:]

for y in goal:
    del y[:1]



print('info:', info)
print('goal:', goal)
```

Output without `goal2` variable:

```
info: ['89426 Green Mountain Road, Astoria, OR 97103. Phone: 503-325-9720. Open: ']
goal: [[' Phone: 503-325-9720']]
```

Desired Output with "`goal2`" variable:

```
info: [info: ['89426 Green Mountain Road, Astoria, OR 97103. Phone: 503-325-9720. Open: ']
goal: [[' Phone: 503-325-9720']]
goal2: ['503-325-9720']
```

I will obviously have more more numbers, but I didn't want to clog up the space. So it would look somthing more like this:

```
goal2: ['503-325-9720', '###-###-####', '###-###-####', '###-###-####']
```

But I want to make sure that each number can be exported into a new row within a csv file. So when I create a csv file with a header "Phone" each number above will be in a seperate row and not clustered together. I am thinking that I might need to change my code to a for loop???

Comment: I ran your code and i had no problems...

Comment: Please see edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleaner approach here would be to just do another regex search on your `info`, e.g.:

```
pat = re.compile(r'\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4}')
goal = [pat.search(i).group() for i in info if pat.search(i)]
```

Outputs:

```
goal: ['503-325-9720']
```

Or if there are more than one number per line:

```
# use captive group instead
pat = re.compile(r'(\d{3}\-\d{3}\-\d{4})')
goal = [pat.findall(i) for i in info]
```

Outputs:

```
goal = [['503-325-9720', '123-456-7890']]
```

Comment: So that only works if I run the code with the first index. As soon as I take it out I receive an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: Ah, there are some that don't match then.  See my updated answer.  Also included case for more than one phone number.

Comment: That works. Could you explain what the `r` is within the `re.compile` function? I ended up changing that expression to the same thing I had within my `info` variable because some numbers included `( )`. Also, is `i` the index?

Comment: `i` each of the text string extracted from your `soup.findAll`.  You can name it something else more descriptive of course. The `r` in front of string quotations denote it as a raw string which eliminates the need to escape each of the `\ `.  See more info on the lexicals here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: Also, if you need to handle the `( )`'s, make sure those are escaped in regex since they have special meanings (capture group) in regex.  e.g. if your first 3 digits might contain brackets: use: `r'(\(?\d{3}\)?\-\d{3}\-\d{4})'`