# How to split each element of a list by last two fields and print them?

Tags: python, list

I have a list as below:

```
['Abc Jkl admins@xyz.com np301 192.168.1.1', 'Abc admins@xyz.com np302 192.168.1.2', 'Abc Txt Zbt admins@xyz.co.uk np303 192.168.1.3', 'Abc Yr Kjs KJ admins@xyz.co np305 192.168.1.4']
```

How to print only last two fields from each element as below?

```
np301 192.168.1.1
np302 192.168.1.2
np303 192.168.1.3
np305 192.168.1.4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split elements of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/how-to-split-elements-of-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do in this way:

```
l = ['Abc Jkl admins@xyz.com np301 192.168.1.1', 'Abc admins@xyz.com np302 192.168.1.2', 'Abc Txt Zbt admins@xyz.co.uk np303 192.168.1.3', 'Abc Yr Kjs KJ admins@xyz.co np305 192.168.1.4']
for i in l:
    print (i.split(' ')[-2:])
```

Output:

```
['np301', '192.168.1.1']
['np302', '192.168.1.2']
['np303', '192.168.1.3']
['np305', '192.168.1.4']
```