# Can elements of a list be split using list comprehension when it involves regex?

Tags: python, list

An example of using list comprehension to split elements of a list is here: [How to split elements of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/how-to-split-elements-of-a-list)

```
myList = [i.split('\t')[0] for i in myList]
```

Can something like this be done using re.split if you want to split on regex? Simply substituting re.split for split in the above along with regex term yields attribution error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're'

So re is not being recognized as the regex library when used in this form of list comprehension. Can it be done?

Comment: "So re is not being recognized as the regex library when used in this form of list comprehension. Can it be done?" what are you talking about? What form? Are you literally doing `i.re.split('\t')`? Why do you think that would work? What library works like that? That never works anywhere, a list comprehension has nothing to do with it. Have you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) or the helpful [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `i.split()`, you're using a method of the string object itself. If you want to use a function from somewhere else, like `re.split()` you can't call it on the object itself - it doesn't know about it.

Instead:

```py
import re 

myList = [re.split('\t', i)[0] for i in myList]
```

If you read the [documentation on re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), you'll notice that it requires you to pass the string to split as a parameter, instead of operating directly on it.

Comment: You're welcome - if it answers your question, feel free to click the check mark underneath the vote counter, to indicate that the question no longer require answers.