# How do you separate every element from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
l1 = [2345]
```

I want the following output

```
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: what would be the output of `l1 = [123, 456]`?

Comment: Refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/how-to-split-elements-of-a-list

Answer (score 1):

use this block of code:

```
l1 = [2345]
l1_str = str(l1[0])
l1_sep = []
for i in l1_str:
    l1_sep.append(int(i))
print(l1_sep)
```

or something like this:

```
list(map(int, str(l1[0])))
```

Comment: One liner alternative: `list(map(int, str(l1[0])))`

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a single-element list then you could do this:

```
li1 = [1234]
li_output = [int(elem) for elem in str(li1[0])]

print(li_output)

>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use a construct like this

```
l1 = [2345]
l2 = [int(number) for number in str(l1[0]) ]
print(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [1234]
a = list(str(l1[0]))
a = [1,2,3,4] output.
```