# How to split items in list?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to scrape information from a website. I put the info into a list, but when I print the list, it looks something like this:

```
list =  ['text  \n\n  more text (1)  \n\n  even more text  \n\n']
```

As you can see, nothing is separated. I want the list to look something like this:

```
list = ['text','more text (1)', 'even more text']
```

I tried doing `list = [i.split('\n\n') for i in list]` but that didn't work. The result was :

```
list = [text  ','  more text (1)  ','  even more text]
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my question and help in any way you can. I appreciate  it

Comment: If your issue is the extra space, you can use the `strip()` method

Comment: Looks like you already got the right result, you just need to include `.strip()` in your code

Comment: Should show the "put the info into a list" code if it isn't doing what you want.

Comment: don't call a list `list`. then take a look at `.split()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/how-to-split-elements-of-a-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code maybe:

```
import re
list =  ['text  \n\n  more text (1)  \n\n  even more text  \n\n']
list[0] = list[0].replace('  \n\n  ', '#').replace('  \n\n', '#')
list = re.split('#',list[0])

if list[len(list) - 1] == '':
  list.pop(len(list) - 1)

print(list)
```

Output:

```
['text', 'more text (1)', 'even more text']
```

First we replace every instance of `'  \n\n  '` and `'   \n\n'` with `'#'`. This is because even though the elements are separated by `'  \n\n  '`, the code ends without a space after it, so we need a unique separator for that instance.

Afterwards, we split the list by every instance of `'#'`, and pop the final element if it was a black space caused by an ending `'  \n\n  '` or `'  \n\n '`.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Comment: This definitely helped! Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there... If you to the following you should be there:

```py
the_list = ['text  \n\n  more text (1)  \n\n  even more text  \n\n']
final_list = list(filter(None, [i.strip() for i in the_list[0].split('\n\n')]))
```

The reason why it failed in my previous answer was that we defined `the_list` as a list of length 1. Secondly, I put the split in the wrong location.

I've also added the filter to "squeeze" an empty result at the end in case you want to remove those.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I got this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'`.  I tried `final_list = [i.strip()split('\n\n') for i in list]' instead. The problem is, when I convert this to a dataframe, it still has everything in 1 row and doesn't split the text into rows

Comment: Oops. I've done something wrong. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it. I first split each string of your list and then remove any trailing or leading space using the `split` method.

```py
info = []
for i in liste:
    if i[-2:] == "\n\n":
        i = i[:-2]
    untrimmed = i.split("\n\n")
    trimmed = [j.strip() for j in untrimmed]
    info.append(trimmed)
```

The `if` statement permits to get rid of any empty string if your input ends with `"\n\n"`.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried this code it's worked for me may be it helps you.

```
lst =  "text  \n\n  more text (1)  \n\n  even more text"

x=lst.split("\n\n")

print("list=",x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 =  ['text  \n\n  more text (1)  \n\n  even more text  \n\n']
print(list1)
list1
joined = "".join(list1)
joined = joined.replace('\n\n',',')
words = [x.strip() for x in joined.split(',')]
print(words)
while("" in words) :
    words.remove("")
print(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this:

```
list =  ['text  \n\n  more text (1)  \n\n  even more text  \n\n']
aux = lista[0].split('\n\n')
list_final = [e.strip() for e in aux]
list_final.remove('')
```