# splitting list entries in python only results in creation of sublists

Tags: python, list, split

I am trying to split list entries, that all have a structure like '50   0.096453' because i want to seperate the two numbers of each entrie into two seperate lists.

I have tried:

```
stimulustimes, stimulusamp = map(list, zip(*(i.split("  ") for i in stimuluslist)))
```

however, this returns the error "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)".
When trying `stimuluslist=[i.split("  ") for i in stimuluslist]` it returns the same original lists, but all the entries are now sublists ['50   0.096453'] instead of strings.

`stimulustimes=[i.split("  ")[0] for i in stimuluslist]` somehow works to get a list with the first numbers (50 etc.) though, which leaves me very confused.

I took this code from another person on this site who wanted to split a list the same way as me and i cannot figure out why it seems to be working for them but not for me: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696027/how-to-split-elements-of-a-list)

Comment: You have two spaces in your split string.. Try `stimulustimes, stimulusamp = map(list, zip(*(i.split(" ") for i in stimuluslist)))`

Comment: I accidentally only used one space in my example, thats my bad. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely using the wrong separator. Are you sure you have exactly two spaces?

Better use the default `split()` that will split on one or more spaces:

```
stimuluslist = ['50 0.096453', '51 1.096453']
stimulustimes, stimulusamp = map(list, zip(*(i.split() for i in stimuluslist)))

# or
stimulustimes, stimulusamp = map(list, zip(*map(str.split, stimuluslist)))
```

Output:

```
# stimulustimes
['50', '51']

# stimulusamp
['0.096453', '1.096453']
```

Alternatively, you have strings in the list that do not follow the shown pattern.

If those are empty strings:

```
stimulustimes, stimulusamp = map(list, zip(*(i.split() for i in stimuluslist if i)))
```

Or, to check that the string yield 2 parts after splitting:

```
stimulustimes, stimulusamp = [], []
for s in stimuluslist:
    try:
        t, a = s.split('  ')
        stimulustimes.append(t)
        stimulusamp.append(a)
    except ValueError:
        print(f'skipping "{s}"')
```

Comment: I did try using split without value, in which case the error "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)" gets returned. Running `stimuluslist=[i.split() for i in stimuluslist]` returns the same list of lists. I realized i accidentally only used one space in my example but it is two.

Comment: @dumpling then please provide a reproducible example of the `stimuluslist` list, you must have something in the data, which we currently cannot see

Comment: `stimuluslist=['0  0.00840817',
 '50  0.008745',
 '100  0.00910241',
 '150  0.00948153',
 '200  0.00988347',
 '250  0.0103092',
 '300  0.0107599']`  is what the list looks like, only longer.

Comment: and on this it works why im crying

Comment: this example works fine for me, what is the output of `[s for s in stimuluslist if '  ' not in s]`?

Comment: The output for me is a list with one empty string. The example i have provided works for me too. This couldnt be a problem of sheer size could it? As the original list has the exact same structure but 200000 entries, not 7.

Comment: Then this empty string is the culprit. Try: `stimulustimes, stimulusamp = map(list, zip(*(i.split() for i in stimuluslist if i)))`

Comment: Yes! This works! Thank you so much! I now know to check for data anomalies next time!

Comment: I added another alternative